# Can I run regression on uneven subsample?

Tags: econometrics, regression, logit

I study the influence of long working hours on health. In my sample 40% of people work more than 40 hours and other 60% don’t. I want to look at the effect of working exactly more than 50 hours compared to less or equal 40. Can I just take all people who work more than 50 hours from my sample (about 250 people) and those who work less or equal 40 (about 1600 people) and run a regression? Is it ok that 250 is much less than 1600? If not, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

In principle you could run the regression on subsample but there are far better alternatives. Any time you are splitting the sample the two subsequent regressions will loos a lot of degrees of freedom and hence the estimates will be less precise. Also, 250 observations is quite a low amount, in a linear regression you should have at least 25-30 observations per independent regressor to justify the asymptotic properties of your estimator and more is always better.

Instead of running 2 regressions if you are interested in knowing effect of working more than 50 hours on the dependent variable just add an dummy to your regression.

You can run a following model:

$$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 D_i + \beta_2 w_i + \beta_3D_iw_i + e_i $$

where $y_i$ is your dependent variable, $D_i$ is a dummy variable that indicates if individual $i$ works more than 50h ($D_i=1$) or less than 50h ($D_i=0$), $w_i$ is the amount of working hours individual works, $D_i w_i$ is an interaction term and $e_i$ is the error term.

This way you can extract the effect of working over 50h without splitting the sample into two subsample avoiding the loss precision.

Comment: As a note, if you exclude the interaction term, you assumes the effect is entirely a transition in $E(y_i|D_i)$ for the two groups. The interaction term shows how the marginal impact of those hours changes at 50.